# Make Coverflow appear like a Horizontal Gallery Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make the CoverFlow below appear like a Horizontal Gallery. The original file looks like this

[image]

There are three classes

1. the CoverFlow.class which extends a gallery

   ```
   public class CoverFlow extends Gallery {

   private Camera mCamera = new Camera();
   private int mMaxRotationAngle = 50;
   private int mMaxZoom = -380;
   private int mCoveflowCenter;
   private boolean mAlphaMode = true;
   private boolean mCircleMode = false;
   public CoverFlow(Context context) {
       super(context);
       this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
   }
   public CoverFlow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
   }
   public CoverFlow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
   }
   public int getMaxRotationAngle() {
       return mMaxRotationAngle;
   }
   public void setMaxRotationAngle(int maxRotationAngle) {
       mMaxRotationAngle = maxRotationAngle;
   }
   public boolean getCircleMode() {
       return mCircleMode;
   }
   public void setCircleMode(boolean isCircle) {
       mCircleMode = isCircle;
   }
   public boolean getAlphaMode() {
       return mAlphaMode;
   }
   public void setAlphaMode(boolean isAlpha) {
       mAlphaMode = isAlpha;
   }
   public int getMaxZoom() {
       return mMaxZoom;
   }
   public void setMaxZoom(int maxZoom) {
       mMaxZoom = maxZoom;
   }
   private int getCenterOfCoverflow() {
       return (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2
               + getPaddingLeft();
   }
   private static int getCenterOfView(View view) {
       return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
   }
   protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
       final int childCenter = getCenterOfView(child);
       final int childWidth = child.getWidth();
       int rotationAngle = 0;
       t.clear();
       t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
       if (childCenter == mCoveflowCenter) {
           transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, 0);
       } else {
           rotationAngle = (int) (((float) (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) / childWidth) * mMaxRotationAngle);
           if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > mMaxRotationAngle) {
               rotationAngle = (rotationAngle < 0) ? -mMaxRotationAngle
                       : mMaxRotationAngle;
           }
           transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, rotationAngle);
       }
       return true;
   }
   /**
    * This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If
    * you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old
    * values of 0.
    * 
    * @param w
    *            Current width of this view.
    * @param h
    *            Current height of this view.
    * @param oldw
    *            Old width of this view.
    * @param oldh
    *            Old height of this view.
    */
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       mCoveflowCenter = getCenterOfCoverflow();
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
   }
   /**
    * Transform the Image Bitmap by the Angle passed
    * 
    * @param imageView
    *            ImageView the ImageView whose bitmap we want to rotate
    * @param t
    *            transformation
    * @param rotationAngle
    *            the Angle by which to rotate the Bitmap
    */
   private void transformImageBitmap(ImageView child, Transformation t,
           int rotationAngle) {
       mCamera.save();
       final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();
       final int imageHeight = child.getLayoutParams().height;
       final int imageWidth = child.getLayoutParams().width;
       final int rotation = Math.abs(rotationAngle);
       mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
       // As the angle of the view gets less, zoom in
       if (rotation <= mMaxRotationAngle) {
           float zoomAmount = (float) (mMaxZoom + (rotation * 1.5));
           mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount);
           if (mCircleMode) {
               if (rotation < 40)
                   mCamera.translate(0.0f, 155, 0.0f);
               else
                   mCamera.translate(0.0f, (255 - rotation * 2.5f), 0.0f);
           }
           if (mAlphaMode) {
               ((ImageView) (child)).setAlpha((int) (255 - rotation * 2.5));
           }
       }
       mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
       mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);

       imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(imageWidth ), -(imageHeight / 2));
       imageMatrix.postTranslate((imageWidth ), (imageHeight / 2));

       mCamera.restore();
   }
   ```

   }

The second class is my coverFlowActivity which is my class class

```
public class CoverFlowActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        CoverFlow cf = new CoverFlow(this);
        ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this);
        cf.setAdapter(ia);
        cf.setAnimationDuration(1000);
        setContentView(cf);

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private int[] mImgs = {
                R.drawable.img1,
                R.drawable.img2,
                R.drawable.img3,
                R.drawable.img4,
                R.drawable.img5,
                R.drawable.img6,
                R.drawable.img7,
                R.drawable.img8
        };
        Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImgs.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return mImgs[position];

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ReflectionImage i = new ReflectionImage(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mImgs[position]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable();
            drawable.setAntiAlias(true);

            return i;
        }

        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            return Math.max(0, 1f/(float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
        }

    }
}
```

and the third activity is the reflected image below each image.

```
public class ReflectionImage extends ImageView {
    //ÊòØÂê¶‰∏∫ReflectionÊ®°Âºè
    private boolean mReflectionMode = true;
    public ReflectionImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public ReflectionImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //ÂèñÂæóÂéüÂßãÂõæÁâáÁöÑbitmapÂπ∂ÈáçÁîª
        Bitmap originalImage = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        DoReflection(originalImage);
    }
    public ReflectionImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Bitmap originalImage = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        DoReflection(originalImage);
    }
    public void setReflectionMode(boolean isRef) {
        mReflectionMode = isRef;
    }
    public boolean getReflectionMode() {
        return mReflectionMode;
    }
    //ÂÅ∑Êáí‰∫Ü,Âè™ÈáçÂÜô‰∫ÜsetImageResource,ÂíåÊûÑÈÄ†ÂáΩÊï∞ÈáåÈù¢Âπ≤‰∫ÜÂêåÊ†∑ÁöÑ‰∫ãÊÉÖ
    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), resId);
        DoReflection(originalImage);
        //super.setImageResource(resId);
    }
    private void DoReflection(Bitmap originalImage) {
        final int reflectionGap = 4;                            //ÂéüÂßãÂõæÁâáÂíåÂèçÂ∞ÑÂõæÁâá‰∏≠Èó¥ÁöÑÈó¥Ë∑ù
        int width = originalImage.getWidth();
        int height = originalImage.getHeight();

        //ÂèçËΩ¨
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(1, -1);
      //reflectionImageÂ∞±ÊòØ‰∏ãÈù¢ÈÄèÊòéÁöÑÈÇ£ÈÉ®ÂàÜ,ÂèØ‰ª•ËÆæÁΩÆÂÆÉÁöÑÈ´òÂ∫¶‰∏∫ÂéüÂßãÁöÑ3/4,ËøôÊ†∑ÊïàÊûú‰ºöÊõ¥Â•Ω‰∫õ
        Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                0, width, height, matrix, false);
        //ÂàõÂª∫‰∏Ä‰∏™Êñ∞ÁöÑbitmap,È´òÂ∫¶‰∏∫ÂéüÊù•ÁöÑ‰∏§ÂÄç
        Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, (height + height), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvasRef = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);

        //ÂÖàÁîªÂéüÂßãÁöÑÂõæÁâá
        canvasRef.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
        //ÁîªÈó¥Ë∑ù
        Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
        canvasRef.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);

        //ÁîªË¢´ÂèçËΩ¨‰ª•ÂêéÁöÑÂõæÁâá
        canvasRef.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);
        // ÂàõÂª∫‰∏Ä‰∏™Ê∏êÂèòÁöÑËíôÁâàÊîæÂú®‰∏ãÈù¢Ë¢´ÂèçËΩ¨ÁöÑÂõæÁâá‰∏äÈù¢
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
                originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                        + reflectionGap, 0x80ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
        // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
        paint.setShader(shader);
        // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
        // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
        canvasRef.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                + reflectionGap, paint);
      //Ë∞ÉÁî®ImageView‰∏≠ÁöÑsetImageBitmap
        this.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
    }
}
```

I want to make it appears like a gallery that is all images must have four dp margin and appear like the center image without any effects. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Comment: You should not use android.widget.Gallery, it was deprecated in API level 16. I have not found any good alternatives as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
private int mMaxRotationAngle = 0;
```

and

```
CoverFlow cf = new CoverFlow(this);
   cf.setSpacing(-30);
```

in the `CoverFlowActivity`

Comment: On different devices cf.setSpacing(-30) can cause the image to overlap one another is there a solution for this

Comment: Convert the spacing  to pixels using int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dips, displayMetrics);  and try again.

Comment: int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -30, displayMetrics); cf.setSpacing(pixels);I am not sure it works.Please check it .

Comment: int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); thanks you

Comment: One last question do you know how to configure this coverflow to work with xml for example      <pl.polidea.coverflow.CoverFlow xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pl.polidea.coverflow"
                coverflow:imageWidth="100dip" coverflow:imageHeight="150dip" coverflow:withReflection="true"
                coverflow:imageReflectionRatio="0.2" coverflow:reflectionGap="2dip" android:id="@+id/coverflowReflect"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need a ViewPager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

NOTE: add the support library to support API till level 4 ;-)

Some usefull code: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    //A little space between pages
    pager.setPageMargin(15);

    //If hardware acceleration is enabled, you should also remove
    // clipping on the pager for its children.
    pager.setClipChildren(false);
```

Adding padding and margin should be trivial ;-)

[image]